# How to get Sendmail to listen on 110 POP3

Tags: email, sendmail, pop3

I'm trying to configure Sendmail to listen on on 110 POP3 on a ec2 server.  I need it for a newsletter app so that it can check for bounces.  When I try to telnet in on port 110 I get a connection error.

```
root:/# telnet sub.domain.com 110
Trying 5?.??.?.?0...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root:/# telnet sub.domain.com 25
Trying 5?.??.?.?0...
Connected to sub.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ip-172-31-54-114.ec2.internal ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1; Wed, 30 Nov 2016 10:24:50 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: [5?.??.?.?0](FORGED)-ec2-5?-??-?-?0.compute-1.amazonaws.com [5?.??.?.?0] (may be forged)
^]

telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

When I `lsof` on port 25 I can see that it's working but not on 110.

```
root:/# lsof -n -i :25
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sendmail- 4279 root    4u  IPv4 2349285      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
root:/# lsof -n -i :110
root:/#
```

Do I need to edit the **sendmail.mc** file, previously I commented out the below lines so that smtp would listen to all IPs.

```
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
```

I've searched the **sendmail.cf** & **sendmail.mc** for any references to pop3/port110 configuration but can't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail MTA acts like SMTP server.  You need separate program/server to service POP3 protocol e.g. dovecot IMAP/POP server.

[Sendmail-FAQ-4.19 : How do I configure sendmail for POP/IMAP/...?](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.19)